# Null error in Activity trying to access SQLite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, fragment

Newbie question time again;
So within FormActivity I post then receive a response from a SQL table on a remote server, the data is put into a local SQLite table row. Then, I have a Fragment with several EditText fields which I try to populate with the local table data. Now, I have a method within the Activity, DrawText(), to do this but when ran I am getting a crash. The logcat message I put in shows that when the DrawText() is called the value it is pulling from the SQLite table is null.

I've moved the method around trying to make sure it accesses the table after it has already been populated from the server response, but cannot get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below (now Edited with help)

FormActivity.java

```
public class FormActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //create variables & Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = FormActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText inputTitle;
    private EditText inputName;
    private EditText inputSurname;
    private SessionManager sm;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String e_check;
    private String surname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

        //set inputs for fields
        inputTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foreText);
        inputSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surnameText);

        //initialise pager for swipe screens
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        //email value passed in
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            e_check = extras.getString("e_check");
        }

        // SQLite database handler - delete old and recreate db from remote server data
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        String email = e_check;
        checkUserDetails(email);
        //<!-- TODO: load db fields to textfields -->
        //<!-- TODO: greeting toast -->
    }
    /**
     * function to verify & retrieve details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkUserDetails(final String email) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_retrieve";

        pDialog.setMessage("Retrieving details ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_RETRIEVE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Retrieval Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user exists
                        // fill in textfields
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        surname = user.getString("surname");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");
                        String tel_no = user.getString("tel_no");
                        String home_add = user.getString("home_add");
                        String postcode = user.getString("postcode");
                        String postal = user.getString("postal");

                        // Inserting row in table
                        db.addUser(name, surname, email, uid, created_at, tel_no, home_add, postcode, postal);

                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Do something after 300ms
                                DrawText();
                            }
                        }, 300);

                        /* Displaying the user details on the screen
                        FirstFragment fragA = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragA");
                        fragA.DrawText();*/

                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Retrieval Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "retrieve");
                params.put("email", email);

                return params;
            }
        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    public void DrawText() {
        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        if (user.size() != 0) {
            //String surname = user.get("surname");
            Log.e(TAG, "string surname: " + surname);

            // Displaying the user details on the screen
            inputSurname.setText(surname);
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "something you want to say");
        }
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                case 3: return FourthFragment.newInstance("FourthFragment, Instance 1");
                //case 4: return FifthFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
                default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");

            }
        }

        @Override
        // Number of screens we want to swipe between
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Logcat (also updated)

```
05-16 09:31:35.560  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots D/FormActivity﹕ Retrieval Response: {"tag":"retrieve","error":false,"uid":"55558b80341dc0.72266271","user":{"name":"John","surname":"Carter","email":"cart@email.com","created_at":"2015-05-15 08:00:32","tel_no":"1231234123","home_add":"22 Lone Road","postcode":"G44 4TT","postal":"false"}}
05-16 09:31:35.643  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots D/SQLiteHandler﹕ Database tables created
05-16 09:31:35.663  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots D/SQLiteHandler﹕ New user inserted into sqlite: 1
05-16 09:31:35.980  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots D/SQLiteHandler﹕ Fetching user from Sqlite: {tel_no=1231234123, postal=false, email=cart@email.com, surname=Carter, name=John, created_at=2015-05-15 08:00:32, uid=55558b80341dc0.72266271, home_add=22 Lone Road, postcode=G44 4TT}
05-16 09:31:35.980  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots E/FormActivity﹕ string surname: Carter
05-16 09:31:35.980  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-16 09:31:35.981  21981-21981/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots, PID: 21981
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots.FormActivity.DrawText(FormActivity.java:180)
            at com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots.FormActivity$1$1.run(FormActivity.java:125)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to collect data before adding data. As you can see you are calling `DrawText();` just after the response received (before adding data to database). So obviously the data'll be null. You should call the `DrawText();` after adding the data to the db.

```
db.addUser(name, surname, email, uid, created_at, tel_no, home_add, postcode, postal);
DrawText();
```

If the above code doesn't work, try calling DrawText() after a 500ms like this

```
db.addUser(name, surname, email, uid, created_at, tel_no, home_add, postcode, postal);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 500ms
    DrawText();
  }
}, 500);
```

If nothing worked from above. declare String variables such as name,surname etc.. ( which you parsed from the JSON ) outside the methods which will extend the accessibility of the variable from any method and update the DrawText(); like this

```
private String surname;

.....{
    ....
    surname = jsonObject.getString("surname");
    ...
}

public void DrawText() {
        Log.e(TAG, "string surname: " + surname);

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        inputSurname.setText(surname);
    }
```

Comment: Okay using both yours and SmulianJulian's answer I now have it running without an error and without skipping to the 'else' from below.
However it soes not seem to run as far as the Logcat tag comments in DrawText()

[EDIT] Sorry, posted same time as yourself, will try this now.

Comment: If you use the handler with postDelay of 300ms, it won't jump into the else.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the second solution,try my 3rd solution. :)

Comment: Nope. I'm getting the logcat msge for the Retrieval Response, but it does not seem to be using DrawText() - no logcat msge form that method showing in logcat, no change in the EditText output.

Comment: If you called the `DrawText()`, you should get the logged message inside the method.

Comment: Right, I had an issue with the PHP webservice that was halting it. With that corrected I am now getting the null exception once again. I have amended the original code to what it is now.

[EDIT] Ah, it seems a problem with the EditText itself in the Fragment, Different issue. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void DrawText() {
    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
if (user.size() != 0) {
    String surname = user.get("surname");
    Log.e(TAG, "string surname: " + surname);

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    inputSurname.setText(surname);
}else{
Log.e(TAG, "something you want to say");}

}
```

Comment: Well it runs, however it is going to else. Is there perhaps a way to force it to wait until user.size() != 0
Or maybe have something like a Sleep(300) wait time, giving the response time to complete?

Comment: try the timer with else...recall DrawText

Comment: It may work but it is sloppy. Working slop beats crashing app.